# How many apples should you carry?

Tags: mathematics

You are on your way to your friend's house. You decide to carry 2 apples to your friend. To get to their house, you must pass across 8 gates. At each gate, the keeper will **take half the amount of apples you have and return one apple back**. The question is, how many apples should you carry at the beginning?

Comment: if there was a lateral thinking tag: start with zero apples, walk through the gate, throw your apple over the next gate, then you will have two apples!

Comment: And that's why I didn't include it, cuz I know some people have an infinitely broad imagination!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need

> 2 apples.

This is because

> Each gatekeeper will take one apple (half of two) and return one to you, meaning you keep the same number of apples through each gate.

Comment: Haha.. Just missed it! :)

Answer (score 6):

Well,

> Let’s work backwards: (2 apples - 1) * 2 = 2. Therefore, you only need to bring 2 apples.

Also,

> You could only bring one apple, and walk through the gates and back. Then you should have around 1.8 apples. Then leave the .8 and repeat for infinite apples! :P

Comment: Ah, I see now. I will change my answer

Comment: Nice one (never thought of this tbh)!

Comment: @Wais Kamal And neither did the gatekeepers, apparently!

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure if it's this easy. But here's a try.

> You need to carry only 2 Apples. At each gate, the keeper will take half the amount i.e. 1 apple and will return it. At the end, you are still left with 2 apples.

Comment: Close one! I think I barely beat you in, but great answer nonetheless! :D

Comment: That's correct, but @El-Guest answered first :)

Comment: @El-Guest I guess yours is.

Comment: Yeah, very close :)